# Operator SDK - Update CreationTimestamp

Tags: go, operator-sdk

I am currently writing a Kubernetes Operator using Golang and the Operator SDK.

In order to know if the creation of a resource has timed out I check the `CreationTimestamp` property of my current resource. After a successful `Update` I want to update the `CreationTimestamp` of that resource, but when I do that, nothing happens and the `CreationTimestamp` stays the same...

My `Reconcile` loop looks something like this:

```
func (r *MyReconciler) Reconcile(ctx context.Context, req ctrl.Request) (ctrl.Result, error) {
    myObject := &v1alpha1.My{}
    err := r.Get(ctx, req.NamespacedName, myObject)
    if err != nil {
      // do something
    }

    //if marked to be deleted
    //do something
    //...


    //if marked to be updated
    myObject.SetCreationTimestamp(v1.Now())

    err = r.Update(ctx, configMap) //updates all fields that I changed except for CreationTimestamp...
    if err != nil {
        println("ERR:", err.Error()) //doesnt get thrown
    }

    println(myObject.CreationTimestamp) //still the old timestamp instead of v1.Now()

   //...
}
```

Or is there any other way to track when the resource was reconciled the last time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think there is a way to achieve this, but I found a workaround.

In your `CRD` the field `metadata.annotations` can store information in a `map[string]string` that wont be overwritten.

So I created a field called `CreationTimestamp` and retrieve it in my go code with `myObject.ObjectMeta.Annotations["creationTimestamp"]`.

I can update the value like this: `myObject.ObjectMeta.Annotations["creationTimestamp"] = "newvalue"` and then doing an `Update` to save the changes